Unable to copy/paste within text editor with RDP session to Ubuntu 22.04
I was able to copy paste between text editors such as Sublime and Vim. I could also do it in the terminal, but now I seem unable to do it.
I can still copy/paste a file both within Ubuntu 22.04 or to the Windows client, but text does not work within Ubuntu or from Ubuntu to Windows Client.  I can copy from Windows client and paste to Ubuntu. I was talking about the generic client settings. The client OS is Windows 11 Enterprise.
The RDP client settings are shown here.
They are checked, but I am not sure what to do on the server side. The GUI is Xfce.

I was talking about the generic client settings. Client OS is Windows 11 Enterprise
